# How do I get charCode when after typing [type="text"] and it throws an undefined massage?

Tags: javascript, events

```
document.getElementById("categories").addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
        console.log(event); 
});
```

It's working for  whole document but

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#categories").on("keyup",function(event){
        console.log(event);
    });
});
```

And it's throwing undefined massages both on "Google Chrome and Firefox"

Comment: I don't see a reason this being undefined. Can you reproduce it in code snippet?

Comment: What **exactly** is the error message and which line of code is it referring to?

Comment: @smnbbrv yea may be...

Comment: If the message is _"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"_, then you have forgotten to include jQuery in your page. Otherwise, I cannot reproduce this at all ~ http://jsfiddle.net/6f52g1n3/

Answer (score 0):

In my case: this code is working in all browser(firefox, chrome,...) If any problem regarding this code please comment.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#categories").on("keyup",function(event){
  var code = event.which;
   console.log(code);
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="categories" name="categories"/>
<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Answers that state _"it works for me"_ aren't typically very helpful